# duplicated JabberId resource on multiple devices

Tags: client-server, xmpp, protocols

XMPP sends messages only to highest priority resources of a given JID. See [1](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html), [2](http://www.jabber.org/faq/#jid) and [3](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/2448)

- I want to create a client that will check all my current resources (home, work, mobile)
- the client will be able to announce itself with one of those existing resources

the hope is that the client will be able to receive messages into multiple devices. This should work.... unless for some reason the service doesn't accept multiple clients with the same resource? is that something specified in the protocol? or something that implementations might choose to allow/forbid?

Answer (score 0):

The full JID is a **unique** identifier, so you cannot be logged in twice with the same one.

If you want more than one client to receive messages, then this can be accomplished by having both of them (different resources) with the same priority and using a server which supports this type of routing.  This is an option under the spec.

Comment: is there a way to query the priorities of other resources of my JID? can you point me to the right point in the spec? is this covered in one of those XEP?

Answer (score 0):

> XMPP sends messages only to highest priority resources of a given JID.

This depeds on your server configuration or server software. There is also server software wich routes messages to bare jids to all resources.

You get all connected resources f your contacts with the presence. So you could also manual send the message to each resource directly.